Support for Confidential Transfers in JS libraries?
Is there any support for the SPL Token 2022 Confidential Transfers in the JS libraries? If not, is it planned?

It's going to take time, but it'll eventually get there -- PRs are always welcome if you find a way to do it more quickly!

Yes if you're using the @solana/spl-token
You can read more from here This guide explains how to use the confidential transfer extension

The guide here seems to relate only to transfers via the CLI tool? I can't see any reference implementations or guides on how to achieve same using the @solana/spl-token (or any other) JS/TS package?
